# How to fetch paragraphs from html using Python

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

How to fetch paragraphs from bad-structured html?

I have this original html text:

```
This position is responsible for developing and implementing age appropriate lesson and activity plans for preschool children, ages 4-5 years-old. Maintain a fun and interactive classroom that is clean and well organized, provide a safe, healthy and welcoming learning environment. The ideal candidate will have:
<br>
<ul>
    <li>AA Early Childhood Education, or related field.  </li>
    <li>2+ years experience in a licensed childcare facility  </li>
    <li>Ability to meet state requirements, including finger print clearance.  </li>
    <li>Excellent oral and written communication skills  </li>
    <li>Strong organization and time management skills.  </li>
    <li>Creativity in expanding children's learning through play.<br>  </li>
    <li>Strong classroom management skills.<br>  </li>
</ul>
<p>The ideal candidate must be a reliable, self-starting professional who is passionate about teaching young children. 
    <br> 
</p>
```

I use Python and try to do something like that:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
```

It returns a new html text with 2 **short** paragraphs:

```
<html>

<body>
    <p>This position is responsible for developing and implementing age appropriate lesson and activity plans for preschool children, ages 4-5 years-old. Maintain a fun and interactive classroom that is clean and well organized, provide a safe, healthy and welcoming learning environment. The ideal candidate will have:
        <br/>
    </p>
    <ul>
        <li>AA Early Childhood Education, or related field. </li>
        <li>2+ years experience in a licensed childcare facility </li>
        <li>Ability to meet state requirements, including finger print clearance. </li>
        <li>Excellent oral and written communication skills </li>
        <li>Strong organization and time management skills. </li>
        <li>Creativity in expanding children's learning through play.
            <br/> </li>
        <li>Strong classroom management skills.
            <br/> </li>
    </ul>
    <p>The ideal candidate must be a reliable, self-starting professional who is passionate about teaching young children.
        <br/> </p>
</body>

</html>
```

But it is not what I expected. In the result, I would like to get this html text:

```
<html>

<body>
    <p>This position is responsible for developing and implementing age appropriate lesson and activity plans for preschool children, ages 4-5 years-old. Maintain a fun and interactive classroom that is clean and well organized, provide a safe, healthy and welcoming learning environment. The ideal candidate will have:
        AA Early Childhood Education, or related field.
        2+ years experience in a licensed childcare facility
        Ability to meet state requirements, including finger print clearance.
        Excellent oral and written communication skills
        Strong organization and time management skills.
        Creativity in expanding children's learning through play.
        Strong classroom management skills.
    </p>
    <p>The ideal candidate must be a reliable, self-starting professional who is passionate about teaching young children.</p>
</body>

</html>
```

For getting above html, I think that the best approach is to remove all html tags except `<p>` and `</p>` from original html.

For this purpose I tried the following regular expression:

```
new_html = re.sub('<[^<]+?>', '', html)
```

Obviously, the regular expession removes all html tags. So, how to remove all html tags except `<p>` and `</p>`?

If someone help me to write the r.e. then I feed `new_html` to `BeautifulSoup()` and get html that I expect.

Comment: Do you want to retrieve the text? If yes then `soup.get_text()` should be fine.

Comment: No, I want to retrieve a list of paragraphs.

Comment: And what about all those `li` tags? do you want to replace them with just the text?

Comment: Yes, and add them in a first paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Short answer

`new_html = re.sub('<([^p]|[^>/][^>]+|/[^p]|/[^>][^>]+)>', '', html)`

## Long answer

Your original regex seems weird. I would have put `[^>]` instead of `[^<]`. You want "anything that is not a closing tag".

Also, it is weird to put `+` followed by `?`.

`+` means : "repeat 1 or more time"

`?` means : "repeat 0 or once".

Having the both signs is quite strange.

Anyway, we can express your regex like this :

"open tag", then "anything that is not 'p' and not /p", then "close tag"

Which is equivalent to :

"open tag", then either "a unique char that is not 'p'" or "anything that is not a slash then one or more char" or "a slash then a unique char that is not 'p'" or "a slash then two or more char", then "close tag".

Which is equivalent to :

`<` then ( `[^p]` or `[^>/][^>]+` or `/[^p]` or `/[^>][^>]+` ) then `>`

This is what is expressed by the regex above.

Here is a quick test to type in a python console :

```
re.sub(
    '<([^p]|[^>/][^>]+|/[^p]|/[^>][^>]+)>', 
    '', 
    'aa <p> bb <a> cc <li> dd <pp> ee <pa> ff </p> gg </a> hh </li> ii </pp> jj </pa> ff')
```

Comment: `+?` means one or more, and non-greedy. Without that `?`, end tags would be captured too. You're right that `[^>]` is better though.

Comment: Why should one use regex instead of HTML Parser?

Answer (score 1):

This is sort of a manual document manipulation, but, you can loop over the `li` elements and [remove](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) them after [appending](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#append) to the first paragraph. Then, remove the `ul` element as well:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
This position is responsible for developing and implementing age appropriate lesson and activity plans for preschool children, ages 4-5 years-old. Maintain a fun and interactive classroom that is clean and well organized, provide a safe, healthy and welcoming learning environment. The ideal candidate will have:
<br>
<ul>
    <li>AA Early Childhood Education, or related field.  </li>
    <li>2+ years experience in a licensed childcare facility  </li>
    <li>Ability to meet state requirements, including finger print clearance.  </li>
    <li>Excellent oral and written communication skills  </li>
    <li>Strong organization and time management skills.  </li>
    <li>Creativity in expanding children's learning through play.<br>  </li>
    <li>Strong classroom management skills.<br>  </li>
</ul>
<p>The ideal candidate must be a reliable, self-starting professional who is passionate about teaching young children.
    <br>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

p = soup.p
for li in soup.find_all("li"):
    p.append(li.get_text())
    li.extract()

soup.find("ul").extract()
print(soup.prettify())
```

Prints the 2 paragraphs as you've planned to have:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   This position is responsible for developing and implementing age appropriate lesson and activity plans for preschool children, ages 4-5 years-old. Maintain a fun and interactive classroom that is clean and well organized, provide a safe, healthy and welcoming learning environment. The ideal candidate will have:
   <br/>
   AA Early Childhood Education, or related field.
   2+ years experience in a licensed childcare facility
   Ability to meet state requirements, including finger print clearance.
   Excellent oral and written communication skills
   Strong organization and time management skills.
   Creativity in expanding children's learning through play.
   Strong classroom management skills.
  </p>
  <p>
   The ideal candidate must be a reliable, self-starting professional who is passionate about teaching young children.
   <br/>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Note that there is an important difference in the way `lxml`, `html.parser` and `html5lib` parse the input HTML you've posted. `html5lib` and `html.parser` don't automatically create the first paragraph making the code above really `lxml` specific.

---

A better approach would probably be making a separate "soup" object. Sample:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


data = """
This position is responsible for developing and implementing age appropriate lesson and activity plans for preschool children, ages 4-5 years-old. Maintain a fun and interactive classroom that is clean and well organized, provide a safe, healthy and welcoming learning environment. The ideal candidate will have:
<br>
<ul>
    <li>AA Early Childhood Education, or related field.  </li>
    <li>2+ years experience in a licensed childcare facility  </li>
    <li>Ability to meet state requirements, including finger print clearance.  </li>
    <li>Excellent oral and written communication skills  </li>
    <li>Strong organization and time management skills.  </li>
    <li>Creativity in expanding children's learning through play.<br>  </li>
    <li>Strong classroom management skills.<br>  </li>
</ul>
<p>The ideal candidate must be a reliable, self-starting professional who is passionate about teaching young children.
    <br>
</p>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data, "lxml")

# create new soup
new_soup = BeautifulSoup("<body></body>", "lxml")
new_body = new_soup.body

# create first paragraph
first_p = new_soup.new_tag("p")
first_p.append(soup.p.get_text())

for li in soup.find_all("li"):
    first_p.append(li.get_text())

new_body.append(first_p)

# create second paragraph
second_p = soup.find_all("p")[-1]
new_body.append(second_p)

print(new_soup.prettify())
```

Prints:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <p>
   This position is responsible for developing and implementing age appropriate lesson and activity plans for preschool children, ages 4-5 years-old. Maintain a fun and interactive classroom that is clean and well organized, provide a safe, healthy and welcoming learning environment. The ideal candidate will have:
   AA Early Childhood Education, or related field.
   2+ years experience in a licensed childcare facility
   Ability to meet state requirements, including finger print clearance.
   Excellent oral and written communication skills
   Strong organization and time management skills.
   Creativity in expanding children's learning through play.
   Strong classroom management skills.
  </p>
  <p>
   The ideal candidate must be a reliable, self-starting professional who is passionate about teaching young children.
   <br/>
  </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what should I do, if I will face with other html tags? Like <h>, <a> and so on. I just want to extract text between <p> </p> tags and add outside text as other paragraph.

Comment: @user3601768 yeah, probably making a separate soup object would be a better idea, updated the answer with a sample. Hope that helps.